# Is there a way in gt() to remove the strange white border around the table when I export it using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to export this gt table in R that needs to have a specific background color because the slides I am using in PowerPoint already have that background color. However, when I use gtsave(), it creates this weird white border around the colored background. Here is the code I am using...what am I missing?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

gtDF <- tibble(a = c(LETTERS),
       b = 1:26) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_options(table.font.names = 'Century Gothic',
              table.background.color = "#ECF5F8",
              column_labels.background.color = '#ECF5F8',
              column_labels.font.weight = 'bold',
              heading.title.font.weight = 'strong',
              heading.title.font.size = 14,
              table.font.color = '#1a1364',
              source_notes.font.size = 14,
              table.font.size = 14)

gtsave(gtDF, 'gtDF.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
gtsave(gtDF, 'gtDF.png', expand = 0)
```

should get rid of the white border. If you want to add borders to the table with predefined colors you can add things like

```r
table.border.top.width=10,
table.border.top.color='#ECF5F8',
```

etc. to your `tab_options`.

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you are looking for as this answer does not use `gt` options. It's likely possible, but I don't know how to do it. So here's a workaround using the package magick:

Note: The pink borders are just to help visualize the effect.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 7.0.11.11
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp, x11
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript
#> Using 4 threads

gtDF <- tibble(a = c(LETTERS),
               b = 1:26) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_options(table.font.names = 'Century Gothic',
              table.background.color = "#ECF5F8",
              column_labels.background.color = '#ECF5F8',
              column_labels.font.weight = 'bold',
              heading.title.font.weight = 'strong',
              heading.title.font.size = 14,
              table.font.color = '#1a1364',
              source_notes.font.size = 14,
              table.font.size = 14,
              table.border.top.color = '#30DB34')

gtsave(gtDF, 'gtDF.png')
```

[image]

```r
png <- image_read('gtDF.png')
image_border(png, "hotpink", "5x5")
```

[image]

```r
image_write(image_trim(png), 'gtDF_wo_border.png', format = 'png')
png2 <- image_read('gtDF_wo_border.png')
image_border(png2, "hotpink", "5x5")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It's a few more lines of code, but it makes sense to me and still runs at a good speed.